# Python / ete3: Target most closely related leaf to a specific species in a phylogenetic tree

Tags: python, phylogeny, ete3

I am using the Python package `ete3`. I have trees such as:

```
((Species1_order1,(Species2_order2,Species3_order2)),Species4_order3,Species5_order5);
```

I would like to see the most closely related leaf to a specific node in the tree (here the tree is `Species1_order1`).
In the example, the most closely related leaves are `Species2_order2`/ `Species3_order2`, and `Species4_order3`/`Species5_order5`.

Code:

```
tree = ete3.Tree('((Species1_order1, \
                    (Species2_order2, Species3_order2)), \
                   Species4_order3, Species5_order5);')
```

New example :

```
    tree=ete3.Tree('((((((A,B),C),D),(E,F)),G),(H,I));')
```

The result I get is :

```
         A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    I
    A  0.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  6.0  6.0  6.0  8.0  8.0
    B  2.0  0.0  3.0  4.0  6.0  6.0  6.0  8.0  8.0
    C  3.0  3.0  0.0  3.0  5.0  5.0  5.0  7.0  7.0
    D  4.0  4.0  3.0  0.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  6.0  6.0
    E  6.0  6.0  5.0  4.0  0.0  2.0  4.0  6.0  6.0
    F  6.0  6.0  5.0  4.0  2.0  0.0  4.0  6.0  6.0
    G  6.0  6.0  5.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  0.0  4.0  4.0
    H  8.0  8.0  7.0  6.0  6.0  6.0  4.0  0.0  2.0
    I  8.0  8.0  7.0  6.0  6.0  6.0  4.0  2.0  0.0
```

But for instance E and F have an equaly distance to A,B,C and D in the tree and in the result they appear to be clother to D.

A good matrix result should rather be :

```
        A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I
    A   0   1   2   3   4   4   5   6   6
    B   1   0   2   3   4   4   5   6   6
    C   2   2   0   3   4   4   5   6   6
    D   3   3   3   0   4   4   5   6   6
    E   4   4   4   4   0   1   5   6   6
    F   4   4   4   4   1   0   5   6   6
    G   5   5   5   5   5   5   0   6   6
    H   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   0   1
    I   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   1   0
```

is not it ?

Comment: Post the code that shows how you are building this tree. Also the last node in your example is missing a `Species` number.

Comment: I think the computed matrix is correct. Try using `tree.show()` to render the tree graphically. `D` is 4 nodes away from both `E` and `F`, 3 away from `C`, and 4 away from both `A` and `B`.

Comment: Yes but from an evolutionary point of view `D` is just as far from `A,B C` and it is closer to these 3 than it is to `E` and `F` for example.  I'm not trying to count then number of node that separate each leaf but only to get an evolutionary relationship matrix.

Comment: There are several ways to define a distance metric on a phylogenetic tree. The one I gave is based on topological distance which is generally the most the most common. Looking at the example matrix, I am not sure how the distances are being computed. `ete3` does support several other types of tree (ClusterTree, EvolTree, NexmlTree, and PhyloTree) but I think for the example they will all give the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, `ete3` gives us a function called `Tree.get_closest_leaf`, but it's output is not what is expected (and I am not sure what this value even represents here):

```python
>>> t=ete3.Tree('((Species1_order1,(Species2_order2,Species3_order2)),Species4_order3,Species5_order5);')
>>> t.get_closest_leaf('Species2_order2')
(Tree node 'Species4_order3' (0x115b2f29), 0.0)
```

Instead, you can get the node distance like this:

```
import ete3
import pandas as pd

def make_matrix(tree):
    def get_root_path(node):
        root_path = [node]
        if node.up:
            root_path.extend(get_root_path(node.up))
        return root_path
    leaves = tree.get_leaves()
    leaf_ct = len(leaves)
    paths = {node.name: set(get_root_path(node)) for node in leaves}
    col_lbls = [leaf.name for leaf in leaves]
    dist_matrix = pd.np.array([pd.np.zeros(leaf_ct)] * leaf_ct)
    df = pd.DataFrame(dist_matrix, index=col_lbls, columns=col_lbls)
    for node1_name, col in df.iteritems():
        for node2_name in col.keys():
            path = paths[node2_name].symmetric_difference(paths[node1_name])
            dist = sum(node.dist for node in path)
            df.at[node1_name, node2_name] = dist
            df.at[node2_name, node1_name] = dist
    return df
```

Note: This is a suboptimal solution for several reasons, but this question is not asking for the most most efficient solution. see [this link](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~durand/03-711/2010/Felsenstein141-171.pdf) for much more information about phylogenetic distance matrix methods.

This solution also uses `pandas` which is overkill, since it is really just for the convenience of row/column labels. It would not be difficult to remove the `pandas` dependencies and do it with native lists instead.

Here is the output:

```
>>> tree=ete3.Tree('((Species1_order1, (Species2_order2, Species3_order2)), Species4_order3, Species5_order5);')
>>> make_matrix(tree)
                 Species1_order1  Species2_order2  Species3_order2  Species4_order3  Species5_order5
Species1_order1              0.0              3.0              3.0              3.0              3.0
Species2_order2              3.0              0.0              2.0              4.0              4.0
Species3_order2              3.0              2.0              0.0              4.0              4.0
Species4_order3              3.0              4.0              4.0              0.0              2.0
Species5_order5              3.0              4.0              4.0              2.0              0.0
```

---

For the updates posted, I am not seeing anything wrong. It appears to give correct results. Here is the tree as rendered by ete3 (I highlighted the 4 hops that are counted in the distance from `Interest_sequence` to `Rhopalosiphum_maidis_Hemiptera`):

[image]

and here is the matrix column for `Interest_sequence` that corresponds to it:

```
>>> m['Interest_sequence']
Rhopalosiphum_maidis__Hemiptera            4.0
Drosophila_novamexicana__Hemiptera         5.0
Drosophila_arizonae__Hemiptera             6.0
Drosophila_navojoa__Hemiptera              6.0
Interest_sequence                          0.0
Heliothis_virescens_droso_3a__nan          5.0
Mythimna_separata_droso__nan               6.0
Heliothis_virescens_droso_3i__nan          6.0
Scaptodrosophila_lebanonensis__Diptera     5.0
Mythimna_unipuncta_droso_A__nan            6.0
Xestia_c-nigrum_droso__nan                 8.0
Helicoverpa_armigera_droso__nan            8.0
Mocis_latipes_droso__nan                   7.0
Drosophila_busckii__Diptera                4.0
Drosophila_bipectinata__Diptera            5.0
Drosophila_mojavensis__Diptera             7.0
Drosophila_yakuba__Diptera                 7.0
Drosophila_hydei__Diptera                  7.0
Drosophila_serrata__Diptera                8.0
Drosophila_takahashii__Diptera             9.0
Drosophila_eugracilis__Diptera            11.0
Drosophila_ficusphila__Diptera            11.0
Drosophila_erecta__Diptera                12.0
Drosophila_melanogaster__Diptera          13.0
Sequence_A_nan__nan                       14.0
Drosophila_sechellia__Diptera             15.0
Drosophila_simulans__Diptera              15.0
Drosophila_suzukii__Diptera               12.0
Drosophila_biarmipes__Diptera             12.0
Name: Interest_sequence, dtype: float64
```

Comment: But the closest leaf of Species2_order2 is Species3_order2 no? @Z4-tier

Comment: @Grendel You are correct. That is strange. I'm not even sure how to interpret that output...  At any rate, this isn't too hard to write from scratch. I updated this answer with a method to compute the distance matrix.

Comment: I updated my question to add a new exemple, there is something wrong in the code ...

Comment: But for instance : `Interest_sequence` is as far from `Heliothis_virescens_droso_3a__nan` as it is from `Mythimna_separata_droso__nan` and yet the matrix says it is closer to `Heliothis_virescens_droso_3a__nan` compared to `Mythimna_separata_droso__nan`.

Answer (score 0):

The ete3 function works as expected, you just need to **iterate over the nodes** of the trees as follows:

```py
from ete3 import Tree t = Tree() # Creates an empty tree 
A = t.add_child(name="A") # Adds a new child to the current tree root and returns it 
B = t.add_child(name="B") # Adds a second child to the current tree root and returns it 
C = A.add_child(name="C") # Adds a new child to one of the branches D =
C.add_sister(name="D") # Adds a second child to same branch as before, but using a sister as the starting point 
R = A.add_child(name="R") # Adds a third child to the branch. Multifurcations are supported
# Next, I add 6 random leaves to the R branch names_library is an optional argument. If no names are provided, they will be generated randomly. 
R.populate(6, names_library=["r1","r2","r3","r4","r5","r6"])
for node in t.traverse():
    print(node.get_closest_leaf())
```

**NOTE:** if the internal node is a terminal node, it will have 2 closest leaves, get them with node.get_children()

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should avoid putting `>` in your code, since it makes it hard to copy-paste. I've edited it to fix the formatting.

Comment: @Hack5 My bad, I had a mess formatting the code. I don't know what happened hehehe